# Where am I doing wrong

Tags: r, function, loops

I'm trying to make an r code to calculate the `price` of imaginary products. It has an unlimited number, but the price changes after you have bought `25` of them. It stays unchanged forever. The prices are `2,5,8,12,15,20`.  Here is my code:

```
n<-c(0:9999)
countchange<-seq(25,150, by=25)
price<-c(2,5,8,12,15,20)

for (n in 0:9999) {
   if(n<countchange) {price=price[1]}
    else{price}
  }

pricechange<-function(n){
  coinssum<-n*price
  return(coinssum)  
}

pricechange
```

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: apologies for not making it clear, I was trying to make a function to calculate how many items I can buy with a given a mount of coins first.

Comment: Don't use `return` at the end it stops the `for` loop.

Comment: Please choose a title which accurately reflects your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I had a bit to guess what you're trying to achieve here, here is a solution for my guess:

```
library(tidyverse)

whatCaniAfford <- function(coins){
  price <- tibble(price = c(2,5,8,12,15,20)) %>%
    mutate(
      treshold = cumsum(price*25),
      budget = coins-treshold)
  
  price %>%
    mutate(afford = case_when(
      coins <= 50 & price == 2 ~ floor(coins/2),
      coins <= 50 & price > 2 ~ 0,
      budget > 0 & price < 20 ~ 25,
      budget > 0 & price == 20 ~ floor(lag(budget)/20),
      budget < 0  ~ floor(lag(budget)/price)
    )) %>%
    filter(afford > 0) %>%
    select(price, afford)
  
}

whatCaniAfford(coins = 1000)

# A tibble: 5 × 2
price afford
<dbl>  <dbl>
1     2     25
2     5     25
3     8     25
4    12     25
5    15     21
```

Comment: That is amazing, thank you so much, sorry for the bad formatting as well as unclear question. I thought I would be able to do it somehow but this is way more complicated than I expected the more I tried to find a way haha. Thank you!!!!

Comment: Its not the prettiest solution, but maybe you can write it nicer from here on by yourself. If the answer solved your problem you can mark the answer as accepted :-)

Comment: Yep marked! I am gonna try and understand your way of looping the price first then I will try to make my own version haha.